# In-Place Merging of Two Bubble Sorted Linked Lists (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, sorting, complexity

I'm following a tutorial on merging two bubble-sorted Single Linked Lists in Python.

- `merge1` does the merging by creating a new list with maybe \$O(N+M)\$ memory complexity that I'm guessing, and [has been also reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226951/merging-two-bubble-sorted-linked-lists).
- `merge2` does an in-place merging with \$O(1)\$ constant space complexity that I'm guessing.

---

Other than naming conventions which are not the best here and is not a concern and I have to just follow the tutorial, any feedback would be appreciated, especially about the best practices in object-orinted programming, practical as opposed to theoretical time and complexities, and algorithms.

```
"""
Module Docstring
This is a simple object-oriented implementation of merging two Single Linked Lists with some associated methods, 
such as bubble sorting, create list, and such. 

"""

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        """
        Instantiates the node class
        """
        self.info = value
        self.link = None

class SingleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Instantiates the single linked list class
        """
        self.start = None

    def create_list(self):
        """
        Creates the single linked list
        """
        n = int(input("Enter the number of nodes in the list you wish to create: "))

        if n == 0:
            return
        for _ in range(n):
            data = int(input("Enter the element to be inserted: "))
            self.insert_at_end(data)

    def display_list(self):
        """
        Displays the list
        """
        if self.start is None:
            print(" Single linked list is empty!")
            return
        print(" Single linked list includes: ")
        p = self.start
        while p is not None:
            print(p.info, " ", end=' ')
            p = p.link
        print()

    def insert_in_beginning(self, data):
        """
        Inserts an integer in the beginning of the linked list
        """
        temp = Node(data)
        temp.link = self.start
        self.start = temp

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        """
        Inserts an integer at the end of the linked list
        """
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.start is None:
            self.start = temp
            return

        p = self.start  
        while p.link is not None:
            p = p.link
        p.link = temp

    def insert_after(self, data, x):
        """
        Inserts an integer after the x node
        """
        p = self.start

        while p is not None:
            if p.info == x:
                break
            p = p.link

        if p is None:
            print(f" Sorry! {x} is not in the list.")
        else:
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = p.link
            p.link = temp

    def insert_before(self, data, x):
        """
        Inserts an integer before the x node
        """

        #If list is empty
        if self.start is None:
            print(" Sorry! The list is empty.")
            return 
        #If x is the first node, and new node should be inserted before the first node
        if x == self.start.info:
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = p.link
            p.link = temp

        #Finding the reference to the prior node containing x
        p = self.start
        while p.link is not None:
            if p.link.info == x:
                break
            p = p.link

        if p.link is not None:
            print(f" Sorry! {x} is not in the list.")
        else:
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = p.link
            p.link = temp           

    def insert_at_position(self, data, k):
        """
        Inserts an integer in k position of the linked list
        """     

        #if we wish to insert at the first node
        if k == 1:
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = self.start
            self.start = temp
            return

        p = self.start
        i = 1

        while i < k-1 and p is not None:
            p = p.link
            i += 1

        if p is None:
            print(" The max position is: " + i) 
        else:    
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = self.start
            self.start = temp

    def delete_node(self, x):
        """
        Deletes a node of a linked list
        """

        #If list is empty
        if self.start is None:
            print(" Sorry! The list is empty.")
            return

        #If there is only one node
        if self.start.info == x:
            self.start = self.start.link

        #If more than one node exists
        p = self.start
        while p.link is not None:
            if p.link.info == x:
                break   
            p = p.link

        if p.link is None:
            print(f" Sorry! {x} is not in the list.")
        else:
            p.link = p.link.link

    def delete_first_node(self):
        """
        Deletes the first node of a linked list
        """
        if self.start is None:
            return
        self.start = self.start.link

    def delete_last_node(self):
        """
        Deletes the last node of a linked list
        """

        #If the list is empty
        if self.start is None:
            return

        #If there is only one node
        if self.start.link is None:
            self.start = None
            return

        #If there is more than one node
        p = self.start

        #Increment until we find the node prior to the last node
        while p.link.link is not None:
            p = p.link

        p.link = None   

    def reverse_list(self):
        """
        Reverses the linked list
        """
        prev = None
        p = self.start
        while p is not None:
            next = p.link
            p.link = prev
            prev = p
            p = next
        self.start = prev

    def bubble_sort_exdata(self):
        """
        Bubble sorts the linked list with respect to data
        """

        #If the list is empty or there is only one node
        if self.start is None or self.start.link is None:
            print(" The list has no or only one node and sorting is not required.")
        end = None

        while end != self.start.link:
            p = self.start
            while p.link != end:
                q = p.link
                if p.info > q.info:
                    p.info, q.info = q.info, p.info
                p = p.link
            end = p

    def bubble_sort_exlinks(self):
        """
        Bubble sorts the linked list with respect to links
        """

        #If the list is empty or there is only one node
        if self.start is None or self.start.link is None:
            print(" The list has no or only one node and sorting is not required.")
        end = None

        while end != self.start.link:
            r = p = self.start
            while p.link != end:
                q = p.link
                if p.info > q.info:
                    p.link = q.link
                    q.link = p
                if  p != self.start:
                    r.link = q.link
                else:
                    self.start = q
                p, q = q, p
                r = p
                p = p.link
            end = p

    def merge1(self, list2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists by creating new lists
        """
        merge_list = SingleLinkedList()
        merge_list.start = self._merge1(self.start, list2.start)
        return merge_list

    def _merge1(self, p1, p2):
        """
        Private method of merge1
        """
        if p1.info <= p2.info:
            StartM = Node(p1.info)
            p1 = p1.link
        else:
            StartM = Node(p2.info)
            p2 = p2.link            
        pM = StartM

        while p1 is not None and p2 is not None:
            if p1.info <= p2.info:
                pM.link = Node(p1.info)
                p1 = p1.link
            else:
                pM.link = Node(p2.info)
                p2 = p2.link
            pM = pM.link

        #If the second list is finished, yet the first list has some nodes
        while p1 is not None:
            pM.link = Node(p1.info)
            p1 = p1.link
            pM = pM.link

        #If the second list is finished, yet the first list has some nodes
        while p2 is not None:
            pM.link = Node(p2.info)
            p2 = p2.link
            pM = pM.link

        return StartM

    def merge2(self, list2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists in place in O(1) of space
        """
        merge_list = SingleLinkedList()
        merge_list.start = self._merge2(self.start, list2.start)
        return merge_list

    def _merge2(self, p1, p2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists in place in O(1) of space
        """
        if p1.info <= p2.info:
            StartM = p1
            p1 = p1.link
        else:
            StartM = p2
            p2 = p2.link
        pM = StartM

        while p1 is not None and p2 is not None:
            if p1.info <= p2.info:
                pM.link = p1
                pM = pM.link
                p1 = p1.link
            else:
                pM.link = p2
                pM = pM.link
                p2 = p2.link

        if p1 is None:
            pM.link = p2
        else:
            pM.link = p1

        return StartM

# Testing

if __name__ == '__main__':

    LIST_ONE = SingleLinkedList()
    LIST_TWO = SingleLinkedList()

    LIST_ONE.create_list()
    LIST_TWO.create_list()

    print("1️⃣  The unsorted first list is: ")
    LIST_ONE.display_list()

    print("2️⃣  The unsorted second list is: ")
    LIST_TWO.display_list()


    LIST_ONE.bubble_sort_exdata()
    LIST_TWO.bubble_sort_exdata()

    print("1️⃣  The sorted first list is: ")
    LIST_ONE.display_list()

    print("2️⃣  The sorted second list is: ")
    LIST_TWO.display_list()

    LIST_THREE = LIST_ONE.merge1(LIST_TWO)

    print("The merged list by creating a new list is: ")
    LIST_THREE.display_list()


    LIST_FOUR = LIST_ONE.merge2(LIST_TWO)

    print("The in-place merged list is: ")
    LIST_FOUR.display_list()
```

#### Output

```
Enter the number of nodes in the list you wish to create: 6
Enter the element to be inserted: -1
Enter the element to be inserted: 0
Enter the element to be inserted: 47
Enter the element to be inserted: 30
Enter the element to be inserted: -4
Enter the element to be inserted: 26
Enter the number of nodes in the list you wish to create: 9
Enter the element to be inserted: -3
Enter the element to be inserted: 19
Enter the element to be inserted: 24
Enter the element to be inserted: -120
Enter the element to be inserted: -120
Enter the element to be inserted: 84
Enter the element to be inserted: 40
Enter the element to be inserted: -50
Enter the element to be inserted: 0
1️⃣  The unsorted first list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-1   0   47   30   -4   26   
2️⃣  The unsorted second list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-3   19   24   -120   -120   84   40   -50   0   
1️⃣  The sorted first list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-4   -1   0   26   30   47   
2️⃣  The sorted second list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-120   -120   -50   -3   0   19   24   40   84   
The merged list by creating a new list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-120   -120   -50   -4   -3   -1   0   0   19   24   26   30   40   47   84   
The in-place merged list is: 
 Single linked list includes: 
-120   -120   -50   -4   -3   -1   0   0   19   24   26   30   40   47   84
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"""
Module Docstring
This is a simple object-oriented implementation of merging two Single Linked Lists with some associated methods, 
such as bubble sorting, create list, and such. 

"""
```

The line `Module Docstring` is probably a placeholder which you're meant to remove, but it's good to see that the methods are documented.

---

```
    def create_list(self):
        """
        Creates the single linked list
        """
```

What's the difference between *create* and *instantiate*? I think this is best described as `Reads values from stdin and appends them to this list`.

---

```
    def insert_in_beginning(self, data):
        """
        Inserts an integer in the beginning of the linked list
        """
        temp = Node(data)
        temp.link = self.start
        self.start = temp
```

There's an `insert_at_position` below: why not just call that with position `0`?

---

```
        if self.start is None:
```

Thumbs up for using the right comparison operator.

---

```
    def insert_before(self, data, x):
        """
        Inserts an integer before the x node
        """

        #If list is empty
        if self.start is None:
            print(" Sorry! The list is empty.")
            return
```

In general, raising an exception is more useful than printing something to stdout.

```
        #If x is the first node, and new node should be inserted before the first node
        if x == self.start.info:
            temp = Node(data)
            temp.link = p.link
            p.link = temp
```

I think this is extremely buggy. `p` doesn't exist yet, `self.start` should be updated to `temp`, and it shouldn't fall through and potentially insert the value twice.

---

```
    def insert_at_position(self, data, k):
        """
        Inserts an integer in k position of the linked list
        """     

        #if we wish to insert at the first node
        if k == 1:
```

1-indexing in Python? That's going to confuse people...

---

```
        p = self.start
        i = 1

        while i < k-1 and p is not None:
            p = p.link
            i += 1
```

I suggest refactoring this to decrement `k` and eliminate the variable `i` entirely.

---

```
    def delete_node(self, x):
        ...
        #If there is only one node
        if self.start.info == x:
            self.start = self.start.link
```

The comment describes a different condition to the one which the code actually tests. This would be clearer without the comment.

---

```
    def reverse_list(self):
        ...
            prev = p
            p = next
```

Here Python's simultaneous assignment `prev, p = p, next` can be useful.

---

This seems like a good point to ask the question: do you know what a *sentinel* is? A linked list using a sentinel node for `start` could avoid the special cases of most of the methods above.

---

```
    def bubble_sort_exdata(self):
        """
        Bubble sorts the linked list with respect to data
        """
```

The meaning of "*with respect to data*" is not transparent to me. I only figured it out once I looked at the implementation.

```
        while end != self.start.link:
            p = self.start
            while p.link != end:
                q = p.link
                if p.info > q.info:
                    p.info, q.info = q.info, p.info
                p = p.link
            end = p
```

So far I've resisted the temptation to comment on names, because you said that they're following the tutorial, but I find `end` to be very misleading. I would expect it to be the last node in the list, whereas in effect it's a sentinel for the end of the *unsorted* portion of the list.

---

```
    def bubble_sort_exlinks(self):
        ...
        while end != self.start.link:
            r = p = self.start
            while p.link != end:
                q = p.link
                if p.info > q.info:
                    p.link = q.link
                    q.link = p
                if  p != self.start:
                    r.link = q.link
                else:
                    self.start = q
                p, q = q, p
                r = p
                p = p.link
            end = p
```

This is rather complex. I could use some comments to explain the loop invariants and the meanings of `p,q,r`.

---

```
    def merge1(self, list2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists by creating new lists
        """
        merge_list = SingleLinkedList()
        merge_list.start = self._merge1(self.start, list2.start)
        return merge_list

    def _merge1(self, p1, p2):
        """
        Private method of merge1
        """
        if p1.info <= p2.info:
```

What if `p1 is None` or `p2 is None`? I don't see anything which would prevent those cases arising.

```
            StartM = Node(p1.info)
```

This could be just `self.start` instead of `StartM` if called with a different `self`. At present the method doesn't use `self` at all.

---

```
    def merge2(self, list2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists in place in O(1) of space
        """
```

This should say something about the process being destructive to `this` and `list2`. And it would arguably make more sense to merge `list2` into `self` and not return anything.

```
    def _merge2(self, p1, p2):
        """
        Merges two already sorted single linked lists in place in O(1) of space
        """
        if p1.info <= p2.info:
```

Same bug as `_merge1`.

---

```
# Testing

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

That's good, but it might be better to use `doctest`.